# Can you retrain a feat after an ASI to gain a dedication?

Tags: pathfinder-2e

A friend is looking to join a dedication he doesn't have the stats for quite yet, but in a few levels when we get our ASI he'll meet the requirements.  He was wondering if you could retrain earlier feats (2nd level class feat for example) to get the dedication once he meets the stat requirement.

Answer (score 8):

### Generally No

> When [retraining](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=522), you generally can't make choices you couldn't make when you selected the original option. For instance, you can't exchange a 2nd-level skill feat for a 4th-level one, **or for one that requires prerequisites you didn't meet at the time you took the original feat**. If you don't remember whether you met the prerequisites at the time, ask your GM to make the call.

Comment: Might want to bold/italicize " or for one that requires prerequisites you didn't meet at the time"

Comment: I wonder what the specific cases are where one could, if any.